# Angular ng-repeat finds array, repeats but data aren't shown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this rest call that returns an array with the right data. I can even print it to the console.

My ng-repeat shown on the code snippet below sees that there is data in the array:

```
<div class="container wrapper" ng-controller="searchcontroller">
<div class="row">
    <div class="center-block col-md-6">
            <h2 style="text-align:center;">Zipcode</h2>
            <form name="searchForm" ng-submit="callSearchAPI()">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex.: 9000" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" ng-model="searchzipcode"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="center-block col-md-6">
        <div ng-repeat="item in searchresults" class="col-md-12">
            <p>{{ item.city }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above snippet combined with this controller will give me an array of data:

```
app.controller('searchcontroller', function ($scope, searchservice, $http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
var headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
$scope.searchzipcode;
$scope.searchresults = [];
$scope.stores;

$scope.callSearchAPI = function () {
    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/address/zipcode/',
        data: "zipcode" + $httpParamSerializerJQLike($scope.searchzipcode)
    }).then(function successCallback(data) {
        $scope.searchresults = data.data;
        $scope.searchzipcode = "";
    }, function errorCallback(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
}
```

My ng-repeat in the html will the give me this:

[image]

Why does it not show the data?
No matter what I do it won't show it ..

EDIT:
Image of the response data:
[image]

[image]

Comment: could you add sample response..how you are getting.. though html should have rendered with this part `<p class="ng-scope">{{ item.city }}</p>` instead of `<p>{{ item.city }}</p>`..

Comment: Could you provide some part of the data you receive? Does it contain `city` in every element returned?

Comment: It does contain city

Comment: Could you expand the `Object`s in the `data` array in your response? Or provide maybe the JSON?

Comment: New edit contains the data structure

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no **city** inside any of the **items** that you are receiving from your api call.

Answer (score 0):

Try copy by value.

**$scope.searchresults = data.data.slice();**

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your code calling callSearchAPI().

I see you have that call on the ng-submit of you form, but is there someone firing it?

Comment: That's true, but you could have got it form another snippet of code. I cant' see it in the code provided, nor I see the console.log of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using <p> tag to show data, try a div tag and see if it resolves the issue. I think AngularJS ng-repeat is not friendly with p tag

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-repeat needs to be accompanied with ng-model so it can bind the selected data.

Comment: Can you specify this a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. The project is using Django Templating and for model binding in Django Templates you use {{ }} so Django compiled the site as Django model bindings instead of angular bindings.

Thanks for all the great answers. Sorry for not saying it was a Django Project.